# Exporting One day data without holding lock , in Oracle

Tags: database, oracle, oracle12c

I have to write a script which will take a day's data from a single table and dump it into another table (where my other process will process that data). However, the table from which I want to export data is a "Live" table which has a high amount of inserts. Any kind of locking (while the export is being done) will not be acceptable. I know that mysql has a way of NOT holding a lock via the "--skip-lock-tables" flag. Does Oracle have something similar ? If not , what is the best way to achieve this ?

Oracle version being used is - Oracle SE One 12.1.0.1.v2

Comment: @Tim: read-only queries take no locks in Oracle.

Comment: Is there any column in this table which can be used to order records by how old they are?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - Yes , there is a column entry_date of type timestamp.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: there is absolutely no need to "read in batches" in Oracle. No other session will be affected by a simple select statement. In Oracle readers don't block writers and writers don't block readers. The only concern (as ArtBajji pointed out) is the size of the UNDO. Plus: if really done "in batches" it wouldn't be a transactional consistent view of the data any more.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name For my own education, what would happen if a DML statement were executed on a record after the read began?  How does Oracle deal with this?

Comment: Oracle returns a consistent view of the data from the moment the query started ("statement level read consistency"). Anything in the table that is changed after the query start is invisible to the query. Any other behavior would violate transactional semantics and the ACID principle. More details in the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/consist.htm#CNCPT221

Answer (score 1):

At the point in time when SELECT starts, an SCN is attached to your SELECT. Any changes to the data after that SCN does not impact your SELECT. Your SELECT reads the old data from UNDO. If this is a high transaction table and you expect your SELECT to be long running, ensure that you have sufficient UNDO space and enough UNDO_RETENTION.

Also focus on good design prevents any potential issues. From this point of view, I would suggest implementing daily partitions on your source table. This would help backing up one day's data easily and help maintain the table in future.

Hope this helps.